# Put a Bootstrap 3 div inside a centered div to center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a code like this-

```css
html, body, .container-table {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

/*Making a div in center*/

.container-table {
  display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container container-table">
  <!-- Main div to hold all Data -->

  <!-- Login Form -->
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">

    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="login.html">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="text-center control-label col-md-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button name="remember_me" type="submit" class="center-block btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I am getting a output like this-

[image]

But I want to have it like this-

[image]

Can anyone please help?

---

### Re-

This Question-

> [Centering Login Form Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588593/centering-login-form-bootstrap)

Is not a solution for my problem, because if u run the codes given and read the requirements, then u can easily find this.

**More**- My problem is not centering a div, My problem is centering a div inside of a div which is already centered horizontally and vertically.

Comment: It display same as your expected. https://jsfiddle.net/bta88dcL/

Comment: Maybe another CSS stylesheet is modifying the position, margin, padding or float of the container. If you don't want to change the stylesheet that is doing so it you could use ```!important```. Yes I know it is bad practice and I don't always recommend it but sometimes you just got to get *"hackey"* |)

Comment: @freedomn-m There is already bootstrap css. Check fiddle again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering Login Form Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588593/centering-login-form-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `col-md-offset-3` to the first element of a row in your form

All bootstrap tables have 12 columns -> your form's width is 6 cells -> so you have 6 cells left -> push your form 3 cells and you have 3 on each side

```css
html,
body,
.container-table {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
/*Making a div in center*/

.container-table {
  display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<div class="container container-table">
  <!-- Main div to hold all Data -->

  <!-- Login Form -->
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">

    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="login.html">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="text-center control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-4">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button name="remember_me" type="submit" class="center-block btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working, if I run your code snippet, I am getting this- http://joxi.ru/Vrw8EngfK3G4Nm .  NP, I have my answer, Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 3):

try

```
.container-table
{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply simply use bootstrap columns  ?
With this way the alignment of text and button inside your login div won't be affected, and you don't need any extra CSS :

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       Your login form HTML here ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Put you button inside a div like:

```
<div class="row">
<button name="remember_me" type="submit" class="center-block btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

and assign text-align:center to that div.

Comment: Satya you accidentally left *div.row* open :D

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body,
.container-table {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
body{top:50%;}

/*Making a div in center*/

.container-table {
  display: table;
}
.vertical-center-row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container container-table">
  <!-- Main div to hold all Data -->

  <!-- Login Form -->
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <form action="login.html" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="email" required="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-center control-label col-md-2" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <button class="center-block btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="remember_me">Sign in</button>
    </div>
      
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```